# Application for wall-mounted information display

Tags: performance-monitoring, network-monitoring

Does anyone know of an app to manage a wall-mounted display? I'm looking for something that can show a couple web pages side-by-side, and periodically refresh them, or flip back and forth between a couple of pages. It should show in full-screen on start up, and have all this configuration saved so if the system reboots someone doesn't have to fiddle with it.

This would display things like build status, network traffic, performance stats, service availability, etc.

I've looked around, and there are "digital signage" application for high-end markets (eg, running airport flight info screens), and "video display wall controllers" that can do some of this but are really designed to run a matrix of 16 big displays, often with networking capabilities, and the price tag to match.

On the low-end all solutions I've found seem to be one-offs: people are just using screens that some application happens to provide, and rarely, using a web browser in a kiosk mode on startup to display the page (seems like most people don't automate this). This just seems like a primitive way to go - surely someone has written this app? Am I using the wrong terms?

(And in case it isn't obvious, I'm on the low-end market here, I just have a single big display I want to show stuff on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Xibo

http://xibo.org.uk/

Open Source, Runs on Windows or Unix and works quite well. I had it deployed in a system with single server and 4 displays throughout the building.

Answer (score 0):

Have Xorg start up a browser in fullscreen/kiosk mode instead of a window manager. You can even run the web app on the same machine, pulling data from the remote location.